# Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain - Android

Tags: android, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to invoke lambda request in Android but getting following error after invoking the lambda method. I have not created any interface class directly passing the parameters to Lambda.invoke method. I Code as per follows

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(),
            AppConstant.CognitoPoolID,
            Regions.EU_WEST_1);
new LambdaInvokerFactory(this.getApplicationContext(),
            Regions.EU_WEST_1, credentialsProvider);

private static void invokeFunction() {
    AWSLambdaClient lambda=new AWSLambdaClient();

    // out.println("Invoking function...");
    JSONObject x= new JSONObject();
    try{
        x.put("Command","GetMyLocations");

    }catch (JSONException e){

    }

    InvokeResult result = lambda.invoke(new InvokeRequest()
            .withFunctionName("LAMBDA_SDK_User")
            .withInvocationType(InvocationType.RequestResponse)
            .withLogType(LogType.None)
            .withPayload(ByteBuffer.wrap(x.toString().getBytes())));

    Log.d("Lambda Result",""+result.getPayload());
    //out.print();
}
```

Error:

```
01-30 16:51:44.027 20754-20754/com.example.sanmol E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: com.example.sanmol, PID: 20754
                                                                com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
                                                                    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:117)
                                                                    at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClient.invoke(AWSLambdaClient.java:406)
                                                                    at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClient.invoke(AWSLambdaClient.java:364)
                                                                    at com.example.sanmol.activities.RegistrationActivity.invokeFunction(RegistrationActivity.java:303)
                                                                    at com.example.sanmol.activities.RegistrationActivity.credentialsProvider(RegistrationActivity.java:286)
                                                                    at com.example.sanmol.activities.RegistrationActivity$AsyncTaskUserLogin.onPostExecute(RegistrationActivity.java:267)
                                                                    at com.example.sanmol.activities.RegistrationActivity$AsyncTaskUserLogin.onPostExecute(RegistrationActivity.java:232)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:209)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5916)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1005)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:800)
```

Comment: Check the title and be more clear in your text. Think the title and test does not have relation.

Comment: but at the time of invoke method it should take credentials automatically right?

Comment: It there a reason you invoke the Lambda yourself and not use API Gateway and invoke the Lambda through HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using your created LambdaInvokerFactory. I think you are mixing up different way of invoking Lambda functions.

Can you use your credentials in the Lambda client:

```
AWSLambdaClient lambda=new AWSLambdaClient(credentialsProvider);
```

Otherwise read the AWS guides on how to do it with the `LambdaInvokeFactory.builder()` like this:

```
public class Request {
    // Standard POJO stuff here modeling the input your Lambda function
    // expects.
}

public class Result {
    // More standard POJO stuff here modeling the output your Lambda
    // function produces.
}

public interface LambdaFunctions {

    @LambdaFunction
    Result doSomeStuff(Request request);
}

LambdaFunctions functions = LambdaInvokerFactory.builder()
                        .lambdaClient(AWSLambdaSyncClientBuilder.standard()
                             .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                             .build())
                        .build(LambdaFunctions.class);

Request request = new Request(...);
Result result = functions.doSomeStuff(request);
```

You need to model the Request and Result models of your Lambda function in the POJO classes.

Comment: @doorstck I added LambdaInvokerFactory factory = new LambdaInvokerFactory(context.getApplicationContext(),
                Regions.EU_WEST_1, credentialsProvider); this method still getting error "Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool."

Comment: @Nayank Yes. But the LambdaInvokerFactory and AWSLambdaClient are two different ways of doing it. You are mixing it up. Either use one or the other. See my edit of an example of how to use the factory.

Comment: I implemented the same as you shown,  check the following code is it correct?

Comment: CognitoUserAuthentication cognitoUserAuthentication = new CognitoUserAuthentication(AppConstant.AashyaAAWSAccountID, AppConstant.CognitoPoolID, context, Regions.EU_WEST_1);
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(context.getApplicationContext(), cognitoUserAuthentication,
                Regions.EU_WEST_1);
        LambdaInvokerFactory factory = new LambdaInvokerFactory(context.getApplicationContext(),
                Regions.EU_WEST_1, (AWSCredentialsProvider) cognitoUserAuthentication);

Comment: @Nayank it is not. You do not 'new' up a `LambdaInvokerFactory`. You use the static `.builder()` method like I have shown in the example.

Comment: is there any simple method for invoking lambda method?

Comment: can we do as per follows: AWSLambdaClient lambda=new AWSLambdaClient(credentialsProvider);
        InvokeResult result = lambda.invoke(new InvokeRequest()
                .withFunctionName("LAMBDA_SDK_User")
                .withInvocationType(InvocationType.RequestResponse)
                .withLogType(LogType.None)
                .withPayload(ByteBuffer.wrap(x.toString().getBytes())));

Comment: @Nayank why dont you use the way they propose? By creating a client from an interface: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/invoking-aws-lambda-functions-from-java/

Comment: my above example is working correctly & it's easy, short code no need to take interface. We can pass our data in bufferarray & function name as well.

Comment: Error:(482, 35) error: cannot find symbol variable 'Error:(482, 35) error: cannot find symbol variable AWSLambdaSyncClientBuilder'